# while trying to install react-bootstrap-table i am getting an error like this

Tags: reactjs, installation

PS C:\Users\ravur\demo-web-page> npm install react-bootstrap-table
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: demo-web-page@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-bootstrap-table@4.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-bootstrap-table
npm ERR!   react-bootstrap-table@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\ravur\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ravur\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-04-27T07_14_51_100Z-debug.log

Comment: What command did you run?

Answer (score 4):

That is caused by the React version you are using `react@"^17.0.2"`, while the `react-bootstrap-table` library is based upon `react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0"`.

Since the difference in version is a major release, you could incur in problems hard to debug, since react could have implemented changes that could have broken the library functionality e.a. reason why npm throws you that error.

At this point, you could either set your project to use react 16 instead of 17 to make sure nothing breaks or you could otherwise keep your version as is and force the library installation as such: `npm i react-bootstrap-table --legacy-peer-deps`.

If you opt for the second alternative, you know you won't need to use `--legacy-peer-deps` for new installations as soon as the library maintainers will update the library to work off v.17.

Comment: Anyone tried this as legacy module?  Wondering how broken it seems to be since both **react-bootstrap-table** & **react-bootstrap-table-next** still have not been updated to work with react@^17.x.x ... seems like the Dev got other stuff to do.

Comment: There are no breaking changes on v17 so everything works just fine